# Reverse for 'add_review' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['add_review/(?P<mslug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\\Z']

Tags: django

Iam trying to add review on my movie project and this error occured.

this is **Movie** and **Review** models  which is in app called **Movie**

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Crew.models import *
from Details.models import *


class Movie(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)
    language=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    release=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    rating=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    audience_score=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)

    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/poster',blank=True)
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/cover',null=True,blank=True)

    duration=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None,blank=True)
    streaming=models.ForeignKey(Streaming,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ott=models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

    starring= models.ForeignKey(Actor,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='actors',blank=True,null=True)
    actors=models.ManyToManyField(Actor,related_name='actor',blank=True)
    Characters=models.ManyToManyField(Character,related_name='character',blank=True)

    director=models.ForeignKey(Director,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    writers=models.ManyToManyField(Writer,related_name='writer',blank=True)
    cinematographer=models.ForeignKey(Cinematographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    based =models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    genres=models.ManyToManyField(Genre,blank=True)

    certification=models.ForeignKey(Certification,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    synopsis=models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    trailer=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# this is the review model, i want to add critic review also, so i made it with abstract class
class Parent(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    # slug=models.SlugField(max_length=50,unique=True,default=title)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='user')
    movie=models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    # rating= models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=rate_choices)
    review=models.TextField(max_length=3000,blank=True,null=True)
    class Meta:
        abstract=True
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
class Audience_Review(Parent):
    pass
```

i was planning to goto review page from this on this url on movie_detail page :`{% url 'Movie:add_review' movie.slug %}`

**this is my path**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from Movies import views
app_name='Movie'
urlpatterns = [
    # function based path
    path('',views.home,name='home'),
    path('view_movies',views.view_movies,name='view_movies'),
    path('view_movie/<slug:mslug>',views.view_movie,name='view_movie'),

    path('add_review/<slug:mslug>',views.add_review,name='add_review'),
]
```

this is my **review template**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top:100px;">
    <h1>Write your review for {{movie}}</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"></label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Write a title for your review.">
            <div class="form-text"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label"></label>
            <textarea type="text" name="review" rows="14" cols="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your review."></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    </form>
</div>
```

this is **views.py**

```
def add_review(request,mslug):
    movie=Movie.objects.get(slug=mslug)
    if(request.method=='POST'):
        user=request.user
        title=request.POST['title']
        review=request.POST['review']
        review=Audience_Review.objects.create(user=user,title=title,review=review,movie=movie)
        review.save()
        return view_movies(request)
    return render(request,'add_review.html',{'movie':movie})
```

What is the reason of this error and how can i solve it.

Comment: Your `movie.slug` is empty. Show the template where you have `Movie:add_review` in it.

Answer (score 0):

that means in

```
{% url 'Movie:add_review' movie.slug %}
```

movie.slug is empty. Please check the  view that renders that template.
Either the movie instance has no slug or movie is not in the context of render(...)

Comment: movie table has already a slug, so my plan was to take the movie in detail page as slug and use it to add to the movie foreign key field so that the review wont display on another movie.

Comment: the movie table has a slug, but the entry that is used for {% url .... %} has the slug not set to something then. Just add ****{{movie.slug}}*** to the template to see if movie.slug is empty.